# Resolve NatureServe and GBIF taxonomies

Tags: r, taxonomy

I'm struggling to deal with inconsistencies in the taxonomies used by GBIF and NatureServe. For example, the species *Speyeria aphrodite* is listed in NatureServe as *Argynnis aphrodite* (this genus-level synonymy affects all *Speyeria*). I can see that NatureServe, to their credit, lists an ITIS name, so matching these isn't impossible. But then I have species names like *Tecmessa scitiscripta*, where the fact that the accepted genus name is *Cerura* in ITIS is instead in the `conceptName` field on the NatureServe API. I'd like to automatically match these, as they are basically 1 for 1 synonymns.

I want to treat these synonomies as separately as possible from issues like species-level lumping and splitting. Yes, ideally I'd have some solution that would also alert me to a poor match because, say, a species was recognized by NatureServe that is only listed as subspecies in other taxonomies, e.g. *Polites egremet*. Using the `relatedItisNames` and `conceptName` fields, I am liable to conflate this with *Polites otho*, with both *Polites* mapping to *Wallengrenia otho* in the gbif backbone. For this question, I don't feel like I need to answer how to deal with this situation as it is much trickier to deal with species-level lumping/splitting and I don't know that a programmatic answer will ever be appropriate. Instead, seeking answers for resolving synonymies that aren't perfectly cross-referenced in gbif backbone and NatureServe.

How can I use the Natureserve, GBIF, and possibly other APIs through R to resolve 1:1 synonymies between NatureServe and other widely accepted taxonomies? The **R** packages **taxize**, **rgbif**, and **natserv** all seem like good candidate tools.

```
# this matches the genus *Argynnis*, which is valid but not what I'm looking for (i.e., not a species)
rgbif::name_backbone_verbose("Argynnis aphrodite")

# this doesn't find the match exactly
taxize::get_ids("Argynnis aphrodite")

# this doesn't include the taxon concept info I need
natserv::ns_search_spp("Argynnis aphrodite")

### how can I link it all together?
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgive the idiosyncratic code. When time allows I will edit to be more minimal and general. But, seems like iteratively searching the NS Explorer fields for alternate names can work well in most cases with 1:1 synonymies, but will not flag splits or other taxonomic changes not yet incorporated in the gbif backbone taxonomy. Here I've implemented something klugey that lets me move forward for now:

```
library(tidyverse)
# define some helper functions

# return NA instead of character(0) or NULL
null_to_NA <- function(x){
  c(x, NA)[1]
}

`%ni%` <- Negate(`%in%`) 

# get example data
pleps <- purrr::map_dfr(c("Argynnis aphrodite"
                          , "Polities egermet"
                          , "Polites otho"
                          , "Tecmessa scitiscripta"
                          , "Peridea bordeloni")
                        , function(lep){
                          natserv::ns_search_spp(
                            lep
                             , location = list(nation ="US"
                                               , subnation ="MD"))[[1]] %>% 
                            unnest(cols = nations) %>%
                            unnest(cols = "subnations"
                                   , names_repair ="unique") %>%
                            filter(subnationCode == "MD") %>% 
                            separate(scientificName
                                     , sep =" "
                                     , into =c("genus", "species")
                                     , remove = FALSE) %>% 
                            mutate(gs = paste(genus, species, sep = "_")
                                   , withspace = paste(genus
                                                       , species
                                                       , sep = " ")) %>%
                            filter(species %ni% c("x", "var", " ", "") & 
                                     !grepl("^[^[:alnum:]]", species))
                        })

# function to iteratively search NS fields for alternate names
alt_gs <- function(dat){
  map_dfr(1:nrow(dat)[[1]]
          , function(lrow){
            # get the ns taxon concept info
            ns_deets <- natserv::ns_altid(as.character(dat[lrow, "uniqueId"]))
            # start with itis
            itis.name <- null_to_NA(
              stringr::str_replace(ns_deets$relatedItisNames
                                       , "(.*\\<i\\>)(.*)(\\<\\/i\\>.*)"
                                       , "\\2"))

            # if itis doesn't work, try conceptName
            better.name <- if_else(is.na(itis.name)
                                   , null_to_NA(
                                     stringr::str_replace(ns_deets$conceptName
                                         , "(.*\\<i\\>)(.*)(\\<\\/i\\>.*)"
                                         , "\\2"))
                                   , itis.name)
            
            # goal is to line up with gbif backbone 
            gbif.name <- rgbif::name_backbone(better.name)
            
            natserv.name <- dat[lrow, "withspace"]
            
            return(data.frame(natserv.name, gbif.name))
          })
}

# run it
alt_gs(pleps)
# ok that I have NA for Peridea here
# not trying to solve the splitting for Polites
# perfect isn't the goal, just want to deal with trivial mismatches somehow.
```